# How to detect if the element after a link is a span

Tags: jquery, html

```
<a class="menuactive" href="/news">News</a>
<span id="menu00" style="display:block;">
```

I need a way to detect that there is a span after a link. And if there is to then assign a class to the a. Example:

```
<a class="menuactive" href="/news">News</a>
```

would become

```
<a class="menuactive hasSpan" href="/news">News</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var menuItem = $('.menuactive');
menuItem.next().is('span') && menuItem.addClass('hasSpan');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

```
// selects the .menuactive elements, uses addClass:
$('.menuactive').addClass(function(a,b){
    // if the next-sibling is a span, then returns the 'hasSpan' class to add
    // otherwise returns an empty string (effectively adding no class):
    return $(this).next('span').length > 0 ? 'hasSpan' : '';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SrCAH/1/).

Or:

```
// selects the span element(s) that immediately follow an a element,
// then moves back to that a element and adds the class:
$('a.menuactive + span').prev('a').addClass('hasSpan');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SrCAH/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 0):

Or this `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/k75Uh/

**Detailed here**: http://jsfiddle.net/T8mJ8/

API:

- `.length` : http://api.jquery.com/length/
- `.next` : http://api.jquery.com/next/

**Code**

`$('.menuactive').next('span').length`